# bootstrap multiselect search get value from database

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, multi-select, bootstrap-multiselect

Am using [bootstrap-multiselect](https://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/) in my project. There in search am tying to get database value by `ajax` request, but it is not appending.

**this is my code**

```js
$('#example-getting-started').multiselect({
    includeSelectAllOption: false,
    enableFiltering: true,
    includeFilterClearBtn: true,
    enableCaseInsensitiveFiltering: true               
});

$('.multiselect-search').on("keyup", function(e){
    var keyword = e.target.value;
    if(keyword.length > 2){
        $.ajax({
          url: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users",
          type:"get",
          dataType:"json",
          success:function(response){
            // code for append options example
            //var data = JSON.parse(response);
            var data = response;            
            $.each(data, function(i, option){
                console.log(option)
              var html = '<button type="button" class="multiselect-option dropdown-item" title="'+option.name+'" style="display: block;"><span class="form-check"><input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="cheese"><label class="form-check-label">'+option.name+'</label></span></button>';
              $('.multiselect-container').append(html)
            })
            $('.multiselect').multiselect('rebuild')
          }
        });
    }
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/docs/css/bootstrap-4.5.2.min.css" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/docs/css/bootstrap-example.min.css" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/docs/css/prettify.min.css" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/docs/css/fontawesome-5.15.1-web/all.css" type="text/css">


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/docs/js/bootstrap.bundle-4.5.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/docs/js/prettify.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/dist/css/bootstrap-multiselect.css" type="text/css">
<script src="https://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/dist/js/bootstrap-multiselect.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/css/all.css">


<!-- Build your select: -->
<select id="example-getting-started" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="cheese">Cheese</option>
    <option value="tomatoes">Tomatoes</option>
    <option value="mozarella">Mozzarella</option>
    <option value="mushrooms">Mushrooms</option>
    <option value="pepperoni">Pepperoni</option>
    <option value="onions">Onions</option>
</select>
```

In my code am appending `html` with `$('.multiselect-container').append(html)`. But option not changing.

Please help me to change the value by search. Thanks in advance

Comment: I think you should run ```.multiselect('rebuild')``` after append all data in the select.

Comment: @ikhvjs Yes I already tried, but it is not working for me please check my updated code

Comment: why you are appending your data inside mutliselect-container ? Also , you need to append options not that buttons which are dynamically generated by mutliselect .

Comment: Please provide examples of your data. var data = JSON.parse(response);

Comment: @Swati: I try to append option with `$('#example-getting-started')` but it is not working. Can you please tell me which class is correct to append the data

Comment: @ikhvjs please check this example https://jsfiddle.net/x1cLfz39/ here i used sample API

Comment: You can try like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/7jeoh19t/) . I have commented out ajax part and added dummy datas see how that works .

Comment: @Swati Thanks for your code, but only Ajax success I try to append the option. CAn you please check this one https://jsfiddle.net/x1cLfz39/ I added sample API.

Comment: Check , with [ajax](https://jsfiddle.net/usqzj3xo/) code.

Comment: @Swati: Can you post your answer I will give up vote and tick

Comment: @Swati It is working please post your answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to  append new option inside your select-box itself not inside `mutliselect-container` and then rebuild your mutliselect.

***Demo code*** :

```js
$('#example-getting-started').multiselect({
  includeSelectAllOption: false,
  enableFiltering: true,
  includeFilterClearBtn: true,
  enableCaseInsensitiveFiltering: true
});

$('.multiselect-search').on("keyup", function(e) {
  var keyword = e.target.value;
  if (keyword.length > 2) {
    $.ajax({
      url: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users",
      type: "get",
      dataType: "json",
      success: function(response) {
        $('#example-getting-started').empty() //clear previous options
        $.each(response, function(i, option) {
          $('#example-getting-started').append("<option value=" + option.name + ">" + option.name + "</option>") //append to select itself
        })
        $('#example-getting-started').multiselect('rebuild') //rebuild your select
        $('.multiselect-search').val(keyword) //again set search-box..value..it was lost when rebuild
        $('.multiselect-search').focus()
      }
    });

  }
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/docs/css/bootstrap-4.5.2.min.css" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/docs/css/bootstrap-example.min.css" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/docs/css/prettify.min.css" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/docs/css/fontawesome-5.15.1-web/all.css" type="text/css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/docs/js/bootstrap.bundle-4.5.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/docs/js/prettify.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/dist/css/bootstrap-multiselect.css" type="text/css">
<script src="https://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/dist/js/bootstrap-multiselect.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/css/all.css">
<select id="example-getting-started" multiple="multiple">
  <option value="cheese">Cheese</option>
  <option value="tomatoes">Tomatoes</option>
  <option value="mozarella">Mozzarella</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Also, when you rebuild your select-box again previous typed get lost so i have added that value again inside textbox  . Please see updated code .