# Javascript Bootstrap Multiselect - Show search dropdown if no options available

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, multi-select, bootstrap-multiselect

I'm using bootstrap-multiselect (https://github.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect) and want to dynamically load the data similar to [bootstrap multiselect search get value from database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68133144/bootstrap-multiselect-search-get-value-from-database), but on initial start there are no option values available, then by default the search dropdown is not showing. How can I still open/show the search dropdown if no options are available? Here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mwd4ag3h/

html:

```
<select id="example-getting-started" multiple="multiple"></select>
```

js:

```
$('#example-getting-started').multiselect({
    enableFiltering: true,
    includeFilterClearBtn: true,
    enableCaseInsensitiveFiltering: true
});

/* Here you have a search field */
var data_loader = [
    { label: "Dashboard", value: 1 },
    { label: "Email", value: 2 }
];

/* Here you don't have a search field */
var data_loader_empty = [];

$('#example-getting-started').multiselect('dataprovider', data_loader_empty);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution is to add an element to the multiselect and then hide the list item

```
let $select = $('#example-getting-started').multiselect({
  //includeSelectAllOption: false,
  enableFiltering: true,
  includeFilterClearBtn: true,
  enableCaseInsensitiveFiltering: true
});
var data_loader = [{label:'', value:''}];
$('#example-getting-started').multiselect('dataprovider', data_loader);
$('.multiselect-container li').hide();
```